# What does 1024 by 3 model mean?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp

I was watching this [video](https://youtu.be/040CfFRJ9Rs?t=3m25)  and Sentdex mentioned he had to switch around 1024 by 3 model. What does he mean by 1024 by 3 model and what did he change around?

---

Edited: Youtube link with the timestamp where he talks about this topic

Comment: When does he say that? Don't make us watch a 17 minute video.

Comment: Add the timestamp link directly or the captions at that frame

Comment: Sorry guys I was working. It's around at @3:30

Comment: Can you please remove the downvote? I've added the video timestamp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At 3:30 in video, he mentions this switching. What he is referring to by 'switch around' is that he is specifying the size of the LSTM being used. The 1024 refers to number of cells (or size) of the LSTM, and the 3 is the number of layers.

In the tutorial page being referenced I the snippet he is referencing is:

```
python translate.py
  --data_dir [your_data_directory] --train_dir [checkpoints_directory]
  --size=256 --num_layers=2 --steps_per_checkpoint=50
```

For details on why LSTMs are useful for this task, check out the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3215).

Comment: no problem, and welcome to the site. cheers.